# Can we configure same node as master and slave in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am having two linux machines where I am learning Kubernetes. Since resources are limited, I want to configure the same node as master and slave, so the configuration looks like

192.168.48.48 (master and slave)
191.168.48.49 (slave)

How to perform this setup. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `minikube` the [Minikube install](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) for single node cluster. Use `kubeadm` to install Kubernetes where 1 node is master and another one as Node. Here is the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/), but, make sure you satisfy the prerequisites for the nodes and small house-keeping needs to done as shown in the official document. Then you could install and create two machine cluster for testing purpose if you have two linux machines as you shown two different IP's.

Hope this helps.